# How do you display data per week, not just for this month but the whole data of a user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sample data here:

```
id | quantity | date
1        1      2020-11-08
2        5      2020-11-07
3        3      2019-12-23
4        4      2019-12-22
```

How would I display this per week? Sample output:

```
November 1-8, 2020 (Latest):
quantity | date
1          2020-11-08
5          2020-11-07

December 16-22, 2019:
quantity | date
3          2019-12-22

December 23-29, 2019
quantity | date
3          2019-12-23
```

This problem got me stuck for 2 hours now.
A short example to help me grasp on how to approach this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you defining as a "week" here?

Comment: Per week would be from Monday to Sunday.

Comment: Note that it's unusual for a column called 'id' to be anything other than a PRIMARY KEY

Comment: oh yeah, my bad that was supposed to be auto incremented let me edit that real quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another column to your SQL result which defines a week the data is defined in:

```
SELECT quantity, date, CONCAT(YEAR(timestamp), '/', WEEK(timestamp))
FROM {yourTable}
```

By using this you get a column with week and you can do further transformations with this as you need.

Also year is first in the week 'name' so you can order by it.